# Cannot use RxJava in Pure Java project

Tags: java, gradle, rx-java

I tried to set up my java project to test some function of RxJava. I used Gradle and IntelliJ.

I added the dependencies in `build.gradle` file as below:

```
group 'com.dan.rxjava.experiment'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.0.7'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

And this is the java code:
    import io.reactivex.Observable;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable.just("String").subscribe(System.out::print);
    }
}
```

The project is built successfully but when I run the program I got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/Observable`.

I had been using RxJava for Android quite a while but never encounter similar issue.

Comment: Have you defined appropriate project structure?

Comment: I only add the `Main` class. Am I missed anything?

Comment: Probably the whole project structure. Wait a sec.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/42971135, sample project configured correctly.

Comment: If it solves problem let me know, I will add an answer to be accepted.

Comment: There is something else that fails for you, not your build file. I have an identical setup and it works for me.  Make sure to check in your external library folder that rxjava is there if it is not (probably) try to rebuild the whole project again.

Comment: Thank guys, I checked and The External Libraries folder has the RxJava *.jar file. Still don't know why it can't run.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Was my demo useful?